# When use remesh mesh does not follow bones

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I tried to use Remesh modifier to create a low poly object from a high poly object. But when I use Remesh modifier mesh does not follow bones. I tried Decimate modifier, so when I use that, everything works great. But I need to use Remesh modifier because Decimate modifier is worse than Remesh. Any help how to repair this or how to convert high poly mesh to low poly on another way. Thank you in advance!!!

---

[image]

[image]

I am new in Blender, so I don't know how to repair this.
The Mesh is static, but the bones move.
I make game in Unity, so I have to export this as .FBX, I tried your way, but I did something wrong and I have on the scene two meshes. Low poly one which is static and moving one which is high poly.

Comment: If you are using an armature in all likelihood you should not be using nor Remesh neither Decimate

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **Remesh**, **Decimate** doesn't save vertex weights. So you can try to recreate weights using **data transfer** modifier.

So here is base setup. I have simple mesh, deformed by **armature**. But when I add **Remesh**, **armature** doesn't work:

[image]

Here how to solve this problem:

1. Copy mesh to other layer and remove **Remesh** and **Armature** modifiers on them. It will be a "Source". By the way, you can do a link instead a copy, by using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
2. Add a **Data Transfer** Modifier after **Remesh** but before **Armature**. In modifier settings set "Source" object, click **Vertex data** and **vertex Group(s)**

[image]